# How to convert Date object format in another Data object format in Java?(No string)

Tags: java, date, google-app-engine

i know that maybe this is a replicated question, but i want to parse a string to convert it into Date object.I'm able to do this by doing:

`SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-M-d (HH:mm:ss.S)");
Date date = parser.parse(propertiesvalue[i]);`

And it returns "date" in this format: Fri Jan 30 13:55:00 CET 2015
But i want to return something like:2015-01-30 (13:55:00.00) Data Object (NOT as String Object). I need it to insert Date in local Google Datastore.

Comment: what is the version of java that you use?

Comment: I use 1.7 version

Comment: but the format that you get is an Object Date (Fri Jan 30 13:55:00 CET 2015) and is not a String !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## String != datetime

Do not conflate a date-time object with a string that may represent its value.

A date-time object has no format. A date-time format represents a moment. A date-time object can *generate* a string. A date-time object can be created by *parsing* a string. But the date-time object and the string are always separate and distinct.

## Avoid legacy classes

You are using troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

## Using java.time

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();               // Current moment in UTC
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" );  
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z );       // Same moment viewed as wall-clock time of particular region.
```

Generate a string to represent that object’s value in a certain format.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu-M-d (HH:mm:ss.S)" , Locale.US );
String output = zdt.format( f );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "instant.toString(): " + instant );  // Standard ISO 8601 format.
System.out.println( "zdt.toString(): " + zdt );          // Standard ISO 8601 format.
System.out.println( "output: " + output );               // Custom format.
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/VzPWJz).

> instant.toString(): 2017-04-15T06:00:58.521Z
>
> zdt.toString(): 2017-04-15T18:00:58.521+12:00[Pacific/Auckland]
>
> output: 2017-4-15 (18:00:58.5)

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).